# query related to Set Collection of java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections

In my project program search bar I am using Set for store retrived value from database
My code for decleration is

```
Set<String> name=new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> category=new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> description=new HashSet<String>();
```

& search query is:

```
stmt=con.createStatement();
String sql="select name,category,left(description,150) from packages where name like      '%"+query+"%'";
rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{
i++;
name.add(rs.getString(1));
category.add(rs.getString(2));
description.add(rs.getString(3));
System.out.println("Length Is :\n Name :"+name.size()+"\n category :"+category.size()+"\n description :"+description.size());
}
```

Result showing on console is :
name size:42
category size: 12
description size:12

But i think all set objects length should be same...in my db There is no null values
Is there in Set collection size  criteria???or there any other problems???

Comment: Check if you have same description for more than one row. If you need data structure which holds list with duplicates. You should use list structure(ArrayList, LinkedList). Set eforce uniquiness...

Comment: Yes i was using before set ArrayList...
But i want unique values bassed on all there element Name,category,discription   should i change query for all distinct values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't allow duplicates.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element.

`String sql="select name,category,left(description,150)`

I think that several packages have the same category and description(if it's the description of the category)

If your table is like this :

```
name    |   category  |   description

Name1       cat1          descriptionOfCat1
Name2       cat1          descriptionOfCat1
Name3       cat2          descriptionOfCat2
Name4       cat2          descriptionOfCat2
```

You will have :

```
name size:4 
category size:2 
description size:2
```

Comment: Namely, Java's `Set` is a set, while C++'s `<set>` is a multiset.

Comment: But i want unique values bassed on all there element Name,category,discription should i change query for all distinct values

Answer (score 3):

`Set` do not allow duplicate value. Use `List` instead of `Set`.

```
List<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> category=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> description=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Now what should be used for replacement of Set
is ArrayList or List which is good option????

Comment: You should use List with ArrayList same as my answer declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Set is an interface that do not take duplicate value. So you must have 42 distinct name ,12 distinct category and 12 distinct descriptions that's why you are getting variations in size.
You can use List interface instead of set, you can use ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

`Set` wont allow duplicate elements. Please consider `List`  instead of `Set`.

Consider this design.

Your Item

```
class Item {
    String name;
    String category;
    String description;
    public Item(String aName, String aCategory, String aDescription) {
        super();
        this.name = aName;
        this.category = aCategory;
        this.description = aDescription;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + ", category=" + category
                + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
}
```

Your data access code.

```
List<Item> items=new ArrayList<Item>();
while(rs.next())
{
   i++;
   String name = name.add(rs.getString(1));
   String category = category.add(rs.getString(2));
   String  description = description.add(rs.getString(3)); 
   Item item= new Item(name,category,description);
   items.add(item);
   System.out.println(i+" item " item);
}

System.out.println("Total items "+items.size());
```

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary Yes making separate list for each field. It is easier to create object and put into the single list.